# Create a bunch of dummy hdfs-audit.log-Files

Tags: hadoop, log4j, hdfs, audit

Need to produce a bunch of hdfs-audit log-files automatically for testing  log4j-Configuration. 
Log4j have to rotate the log-file if the file size is greater than 100 MB. But the test-environment produce only 1 MB of log-file a day and the productive-environment about of hundred Gigabyte. First need to test the configuration, before deploying this on a productive Server.

Please help me to find out any technique to produce these log-file in a short period of time.

Best regards
Dominik

Comment: The only way you'll generate audit data is to actually perform actions against the system

Comment: Ist correct, But for my test I need dummy-Log-Files. (A lot of dummy-Log-Files with a huge variety)

Comment: Okay, so write a script.